# Material bottom bar design

Tags: react-native

[image]

How to create this bottom bar design.

Comment: Have a try https://github.com/10clouds/FluidBottomNavigation-rn npm for fluid transitions in the bottom tab bar

Answer (score -1):

You can add some extra CSS to add this rounded padding on the active class. Use pseudo elements ( ::before / ::after ).